# App crashes from app store, but not in development version

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, release

This is a question/answer.  I found my issue which i will explain here hopefully for others to learn from as well, but i also have some questions regarding *why*.

I implemented IAP in my app and tested all of them in sandbox mode and everything worked as planned with no crashes anywhere.  I eventually uploaded my app to the app store and after approval, i removed the development version from my device and installed the app store version.  At which point, when i tried to go to my menu to test my *Remove Ads* IAP in production, the app crashes when loading the VC.

So i looked at my devices logs in Xcode...

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100054a34
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Connectify                      0x0000000100054a34 specialized SettingsTableViewController.(viewDidLoad() -> ()).(closure #1) (SettingsTableViewController.swift:40)
1   Connectify                      0x0000000100054e00 partial apply for SettingsTableViewController.(viewDidLoad() -> ()).(closure #1) (SettingsTableViewController.swift:0)
2   Connectify                      0x00000001000283d0 thunk (IAPHelper.swift:0)
3   Connectify                      0x000000010002b990 specialized IAPHelper.productsRequest(SKProductsRequest, didReceive : SKProductsResponse) -> () (IAPHelper.swift:0)
4   Connectify                      0x0000000100028738 @objc IAPHelper.productsRequest(SKProductsRequest, didReceive : SKProductsResponse) -> () (IAPHelper.swift:0)
5   StoreKit                        0x000000019ae39dbc __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 512
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d229200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d2291c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d22dd6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e34bf2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e349b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e278048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018fcfe198 GSEventRunModal + 180
13  UIKit                           0x00000001942642fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
14  UIKit                           0x000000019425f034 UIApplicationMain + 208
15  Connectify                      0x0000000100021248 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018d25c5b8 start + 4
```

Which lead me to believe it has to do with IAP's.  This code is in `viewDidLoad` of my `SettingsTableViewController`.

```
products = []
Products.store.requestProducts{success, products in
   if success {
      self.products = products!
      for i in 0...products!.count - 1{
         print("Index \(i): \(products![i].productIdentifier)")
      }
      if !IAPHelper.canMakePayments() || Products.store.isProductPurchased(Products.RemoveAds){
         self.cell1.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
         self.cell1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
         self.cell1.accessoryType = .none
         self.cell2.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
         self.cell2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
         self.cell2.accessoryType = .none
      }
  }else{
      print("Not success")
  }
}
```

But i can't decipher enough of the crash log to determine what the issue is, only that it probably has to do with this block of code.

**The revalation**

So, at a loss, i had my wife download the app from the store and test for this crash.  It did not!  No crash at all.  It was at this point I thought to try removing my device from the Dev Portal.  And of course, that fixed it.

**Conclusion/Questions**

*If you're using IAP's, which work in debug build testing, but not in production release on the same device.  Disable your device in the Dev Portal and re-install from the store.*

1) How is Apple deciding when the IAP should be sandboxed? Is it certificate based? Is it if the device ID is registered as a development device?

2) Why would this IAP code work in a debug build on my development device, but not with a release build? (Until i disabled the device in the DevPortal)

3) What information can be gathered from the crash log that would pin point this issue more accurately?

***UPDATE***

After reading more into `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)` when it comes to Swift, i think it it's most likely related to an *index out of bounds exception* in the `Products` array.  Specifically, as the crash report says, this line...

```
for i in 0...products!.count - 1{
```

But why would `products` be `nil` just because the development device is requesting IAPs from the production server?

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as too broad....  I asked 3 (edited to 4) very specific questions.  I've just provided a lot of information.

Comment: I'm in an even "funnier" situation: my app, already successfully submitted at least 20 times while containing IAPs, is now crashing for App Review with almost the same crash log, and for the same code. I can't reproduce it on my machine, including a VM which was never signed in for development. I also tried to avoid the forced unwrap in `self.products = products!`, but crashed again. I don't want to use App Review as beta testers, but I have no way to actually test this.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup How did you resolve this issue? I am facing same crash. but my application is not using IAP.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I don’t recall the exact fix, but I believe I just conditionally unwrapped the optional. So even if you don’t use IAP, check for any other dev/prod calls that might be optional.